# Unable to find unique elements in 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes -

> df1 = Dataset file which contains info about
> `img` files
>  df2 = It is a simple Pandas data frame of number of
> files in a folder which I created using below code -

```
binary_folder_files = os.listdir(binary_folder_path)
binary_list_df = pd.DataFrame(binary_folder_files, columns=['img'])
```

The total number of files in df1 & binary_list_df are - 8239 & 8241 respectively.

 I am unable to find the elements which are uncommon among each other.
 I tried the below method but I am getting empty dataframes on printing both `unique_to_df1` & `unique_to_df2` -

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, binary_list_df, on='img', how='outer', indicator=True)
unique_to_df1 = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only']
unique_to_df2 = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'right_only']
```

I am unable to figure out where I am doing wrong or how to troubleshoot this further -

Below is the sample data frame samples and their expected result-

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'img': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35],
    'City': ['New York', 'San Francisco', 'Chicago']
})


binary_list_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'img': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Frank'],
    'Salary': [50000, 60000, 70000, 80000],
    'Department': ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Engineering', 'Finance']
})
```

Expected Output -
I want only the response for the `Frank field` or just want to know that `Frank` was the intersection.

Comment: it would help if you give some samples from the dfs and what the expected result may be

Comment: using your code i am getting that frank is in unique_to_df2 and i am not getting empty dfs. i think that's your expected output ? maybe something else is wrong

Comment: @zaki98, Exactly that's what I am not able to troubleshoot since past 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

Apply set [symmetric difference](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference) to get elements contained in either 1st or 2nd set but not both:

```
uncommon_imgs = set(df1['img']) ^ set(binary_list_df['img'])
```

Comment: It is coming out to be an empty set

Comment: @Beginner, that means that all items are common between both of your input datasets, and what you might see as difference in quantity does not mean they have uncommon items cause some items can be duplicated

Comment: I did check for the duplicate elements but I got nothing `pent_list_df[pent_list_df.duplicated(keep=False)]`

Comment: @Beginner what about when you select subset in duplicated: df.duplicated(subset=["img"])

Comment: I got 164 samples, now those are different than my initial number also. What's happening here?

Comment: @Beginner, check on your sample dfs and you'll see how `Frank` is extracted

Comment: @Beginner because a row can have same img but has different data on other columns and pandas will check that all the data on the different cols is the same. when you call duplicated with subset="img" it will not check other columns and it will consider an item duplicate just by looking at the img col

Comment: Yes, @zaki98 You nailed it correctly. Found the error. I can peacefully sleep now. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the Pandas `isin` method combined with the `~` operator to achieve this :

```py
binary_list_df[~binary_list_df['img'].isin(df1['img'])]['img']
```

```
3    Frank
Name: img, dtype: object
```

Or if you want the entire Franck row :

```py
binary_list_df[~binary_list_df['img'].isin(df1['img'])]
```

```
     img  Salary Department
3  Frank   80000    Finance
```